# Installing software via chef recipe or chef resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a question regarding the installation of software in a chef cookbook. For the questions sake, please assume that there is no chef cookbook providing this functionality.

Say I want to install nginx from source. I see some sources online archiving this by using a chef recipe. However some sources use chef resources and the `action :install`, where they basically define a chef recipe.

Where is the difference in these approaches. In both cases I could stop the nginx service by either doing so via bash in a recipe or the `nginx_ressource :stop` functionality (which would wrap a bash command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about cookbooks heavy on recipe code vs. cookbooks heavier on custom resources. Recipe code is the heart of Chef, but it turns out that trying to write a single recipe file that can handle all the various use cases on a community cookbook leads to code that is borderline impossible to maintain. As such, most major community cookbooks have moved to a new style using a lot more custom resources, some actually have nothing else in them anymore. For simpler cookbooks that only have to address one use case, either way works.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it is "just" about code maintainability? Do you happen to know any good resources dealing with that topic?

Comment: The best resource is to hang out on Slack and ask questions. Building highly reusable cookbooks is both somewhat complex and a matter of personal taste. If you compare my cookbooks to tas50's or someara's you'll find we each have our own style, though there are a lot of commonalities. Check out Tim Smith's talk on writing reusable cookbooks from ChefConf 2017.

Comment: Thanks, just went through that talk. Quite an excellent overview describing which framework to use for what. Here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jo1Y31O5bPU (I know links die, but I'D find it helpful).